# How to dynamically insert images who's filenames are stored in sqlite into a table served by flask?

Tags: python, html, linux, jinja2

```
{% for record in records %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ record.confidence_int }}</td>
                <td>
                    <img src="file:///home/linuxbld/sdcard/{{ record.image_location }}" width="128" height="128" />
                </td>
```

I am using Flask and sqlite to populate a table on a webpage. The image name is stored in the sqlite database and the actual images are stored on an SD card (embedded device). How can I insert the images as thumbnails into my table? Thank you.

Edit: Perhaps a dynamic link from the SD card to Flask's 'static'?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a symbolic link between the sdcard directory and Flask's static directory:

```
<img src="static/sdcard/{{ record.image_location }}" width="128" height="128" />
```